# How to replace values in a file using sed

Tags: linux, shell

I need to replace few  values and remove the "#" symbol for this lines in the below file using sed in my shell script.

Below are the lines to be replaced:

```
#RateLimitInterval = 30s
#RateLimitBurst = 1000
```

Replacement value:

```
RateLimitInterval = 60s
RateLimitBurst = 10000
```

File is as below

```
#Storage=auto
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
#RateLimitInterval=30s
#RateLimitBurst=1000
#SystemMaxUse=
#SystemKeepFree=
#SystemMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#MaxRetentionSec=
#MaxFileSec=1month
#ForwardToSyslog=yes
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
#LineMax=48K
```

The code which I wrote:

```
sed -i.bk '/#RateLimit/ s/#//; /RateLimitInterval/ s/30s/60s/; /RateLimitBurst/ s/1000/10000/' check_jounal.conf
```

Can Someone provide me suggestions  to optimize this code, feel like it is too long !!

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Post relevant parts of the code that you've tried, show the errors you got, and the effort you made. SO is NOT a: write code service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e '/RateLimitInterval/{s/30/60/; s/^#//;}' \
     -e '/RateLimitBurst/{s/1000/10000/; s/^#//;}'
```

I strongly recommend against using `-i`.  It seems a bit fragile to try to match the current RHS on each line, so you might prefer `s/=.*/=60/'` and `s/=.*/=10000/'`

Answer (score 2):

I would just spell out the replacements in their entirety:

```
sed \
    -e 's/^#RateLimitInterval=30s$/RateLimitInterval=60s/' \
    -e 's/^#RateLimitBurst=1000$/RateLimitBurst=10000/'
```

By default, `sed` accepts its input on standard input and writes to standard output. You can add a filename to read the original from a file; add `--in-place` (`-i`) to also write the replacement to the same file.